# DHCP for wireless, fixed for others

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, wifi

I've run into a situation where I need to have DHCP running for my wireless clients and fixed IPs for everything else.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this, tried searching here on serverfault, google, read the docs for my dsl router/wireless APs. The best i've found was one guy here in serverfault asking a similar question (he wanted to scopes for two different networks).

Making it clear.
I have a network, lets say 192.168.0.xxx and I want to have DHCP running, serving the 192.168.0.100-200 for wireless clients only. Is it possible?

I have available to me windows and linux servers, a linksys WAG120N and a Ubiquity Networks Powerstation2 17D.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: the reason I am asking this is that there is another network running the same physical network, a 10.82.*.* network that uses DHCP and that I cant manage.
The thing is, that network doesnt use anything wireless, and I have on the second network (192.) some wireless clients (mostly notebooks and smartphones) that I didnt want to assign static IPs to.

Comment: Sure is this possible. Just set it up! I can't see the real question here.

Comment: Do you want to hand out addresses to your wireless clients using any DHCP server?  Or do you want to use the one on 10.82.xx.xx?  Also, what make & model of router separates the wired and wireless networks?

Answer (score 2):

What am I missing here?  If you have a DHCP server handing out addresses from 192.168.0.100 - 200... then... just set static IP addresses on the wired clients and you're done.  They won't get DHCP addresses, and the wireless devices, as long as they're configured to get DHCP addresses, will.

Comment: My bad, my question missed this piece of information that makes the rest make sense :)
There is another network runing the same cables, a 10.82.*.* network that uses DHCP and that I cant touch.
The thing is that network doesnt use anything wireless, and I have on the second network (192.) some wireless clients (mostly notebooks and smartphones) that I didnt want to assign static IPs to.

Answer (score 0):

Get the MAC address of the NICs which need to be fixed and assign their ip in the dhcpd.conf file outside of the dhcp range defined for dynamic IP address.

I'm not much of RTFM but in this case **man dhcpd.conf** has examples on setting a range and setting an address for determinate MAC address.

Comment: just fount that you aren't using a *nix dhcp sorry...

Comment: Says who? And even if; then it is a one hour job to get it running on a *nix machine.